# Get set of coordinates for white pixels in a binary image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, binary, coordinates

I'm looking for a fast way to convert a binary image to coordinates representing white pixels. I could ofcourse do two for loops and get all the data, but there must be a faster way.

Example:

```
input
a = [1 0 0;
     0 0 0;
     1 1 0]

result
x = [1 1 2]
y = [1 3 3]
```

Comment: `[y,x]=find(a);` Look at the documentation for the [`find`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function

Comment: Thank you! I always read find is slow, is there anything faster than find?

Comment: I'm curious, where did you read `find` slow?

Comment: I believe that find is said to be slow compared to logical indexing. I am not sure if this is true (or in that case why it would be) since the code is not published, but I would think this is root of these rumors.